# How to optimize SELECT MaxDate

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance, sql-server-2008

I have a query to select some data from tableA matching some rows in tableB. Even though it works it's really slow, it takes about 20 min to return a few hundred rows. Here is the query, hope you have some suggestions where to improve or what to change.

I am using SQL Server 2008

```
DECLARE @MaxDate DATETIME

SELECT @MaxDate = MAX(TimeStamp) -- I know it's not the best column name
FROM tableA
WHERE CodeName IN
(SELECT Tag FROM TableB 
WHERE POSITION = 'UP' AND PLACE = 'Shelf') 

IF @MaxDate > '2011-08-08'
BEGIN

 SELECT @MaxDate = MAX(TimeStamp) -- I know it's not the best column name
FROM tableA
WHERE CodeName IN
(SELECT Tag FROM TableB 
WHERE POSITION = 'UP' AND PLACE = 'Shelf')AND TimeStamp >= '2008-12-24' AND TimeStamp < '2010-12-24'

END
ELSE 
PRINT 'Date out of range'
```

Comment: Can you show the execution plan?

Comment: @Bender . . . How large are these tables?  I suspect that you are using views rather than tables, and that is where the performance problem lies.

Comment: Do you have a covered index on `tableA` over `(TimeStamp, CodeName)`? Do you have a covered index on `tableB` over `(POSITION, PLACE)`?

Comment: the tables are really large, since data is getting updated in it every 2 min, thats why I do a query where the selection includes only specific criteria.

Comment: I will look up the covered index because I dont know much about it. I have some SQL knoledge but there is still a long way to go

Comment: @Bender, a covered index means that there is an `INDEX` that contains all the fields that are being leveraged in the query. So in other words, is there an `INDEX` on `tableA` on the two fields `TimeStamp, CodeName`?

Comment: Yes there is, as far as i understand covered index, but if I am not wrong maybe as covered index the field position and place should be used

Comment: What is your primary key on both tables? Can we get schema information for the tables?

Comment: You can try how fast the: SELECT YourPrimaryKey, TimeStamp 
FROM tableA
WHERE CodeName IN
(SELECT Tag FROM TableB 
WHERE POSITION = 'UP' AND PLACE = 'Shelf')

Comment: @AndrásOttó actually I had a better look at the table, I don't have a primary key, and the query you posted executs for a really long time around 20 min and still doesn't returns all the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery looks fishy and you risk a table scan for every row in tableA. You also only need one query and the shouldn't reuse the variable for something else anyway.

Make sure Codename, Tag, Position and Tag are properly indexed. If "up"/"shelf" tags are not super common you should be able to get away with a table seek of tableA.

```
    SELECT
        @MaxDate  = MAX(TimeStamp),
        @MaxDate2 = MAX(                
            CASE WHEN 
                TimeStamp >= '2008-12-24' AND
                TimeStamp < '2010-12-24'
                THEN TimeStamp END)
    FROM
        tableA A
    JOIN
        Tag T ON 
            T.CodeName=A.Tag 
    WHERE   
        T.POSITION = 'UP' AND
        T.PLACE = 'Shelf'
```

And do something appropriate with the results

```
IF @MaxDate > '2011-08-08'
BEGIN
    SELECT @MaxDate2
END
ELSE 
PRINT 'Date out of range'
```

Comment: You are right that 'UP' AND 'Shelf' are not so common, and I guess the reason why it's so slow is because it checks all rows in the table.

Comment: This query completes pretty fast, but now I'm a bit confused because I don't get any results, I get only a message that query completed successfuly, should I put the rest of the select query after this one executes?

Comment: I guess you should do something with your variables, try to select or print the values? I added to the answer.

Comment: This one works pretty cool, I accept it as an answer because it is helpful, thanks for your time